# Visual studio code for java is not compiling and keeps loading importing projects

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Every code that used to work for me is now not running on visual studio

When I run it, I get this:
This message keeps loading forever without compiling my code :

[image]

when I click on check details I get this:

Debug(command:java.show.server.task.status): Importing projects, check details(command:java.show.server.task.status)

Comment: When it's hanging, it looks like the language server is in a bad state. If the language server is ready, there will be an icon  in the right bottom corner. Or `Java: Clean Java Language workspace` from command palette and create `launch.json` then debug again, does the question still exist?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT Worked in my case. Beer for you . Thanks

Comment: @Praveen. My pleasure, happy coding:)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. Seems to be fixed by clearing the Java workspace, which you can access with ctrl+shift+p.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I updated VSCode first but still had same issue. Then updated the java version from 20 to 21 then everything started to run normal.

Here is my VSCode version:

```
Version: 1.84.0 (Universal)
Commit: d037ac076cee195194f93ce6fe2bdfe2969cc82d
Date: 2023-11-01T11:30:19.406Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your vscode version.Maybe update your version can help.